# Why is memoization not a language feature?

Tags: language-agnostic, memoization

I was wondering: why is memoization not provided natively as a language feature in any language I know about?

**Edit**: to clarify, what I mean is that the language provides a keyword to specify a given function as memoizable, not that every function is automatically memoized "by default" unless specified otherwise. For example, Fortran provides the keyword PURE to specify a specific function as such. I guess that the compiler can take advantage of this information to memoize the call, but I ignore what happens if you declare PURE a function with side effects.

Comment: For people like me who don't know what it is: In computing, memoization is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by having function calls avoid repeating the calculation of results for previously-processed inputs.

Comment: Thanks Koper. Indeed I should have been a bit more didactic.

Comment: Because they didn't get the memo :-)

Comment: Don't you mean 'library' rather than 'language feature'? Are you asking for each and every function to be automatically memoized?

Comment: no, to have a language keyword "memoized" like you have a keyword "synchronized" in java

Comment: @bmargulies: It might be that they heard about it before, but their brain didn't automatically memoize the definition.

Comment: Isn't such keyword `pure` (btw., most C++ compilers also support that) then the thing you want? Whereby I think no compiler yet really adds memoization in such cases but at least they could and maybe they will at some point.

Comment: Btw., in Python, it is quite easy to have such a thing in a straight forward way: [Memoize in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize)

Comment: Python _does_ have that exact thing in the standard library. `@functools.lru_cache()  def ...`

Comment: @Veky: In fact, I said _language_ feature. the lru decorator is a library functionality.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, _standard_ library _are_ language features. In fact, something is core language only if it _cannot_ be supported adequately through stdlib. There is nothing to be gained by putting in core something that stdlib can handle. Does Python support regular expressions? Of course. Iterator chaining? Sure. Trigonometry? You bet. Interfacing with OS? It would be really misleading to say those are not language features, IMO.

Comment: In some languages, the implementation of memoization is so straightforward (without any libraries), and so commonly used, that you might even consider this a language feature. E.g. in Mathematica, Fibonacci *without* memoization: `fib[0] = fib[1] = 1; fib[n_] := fib[n-1] + fib[n-2]`.  With memoization: `fib[0] = fib[1] = 1; fib[n_] := fib[n] = fib[n-1] + fib[n-2]`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What YOU want from memoization may not be the same as what the compiler memoization option would provide.

You may know that it is only profitable to memoize the last 10 or so distinct values computed, because you know how the function will be used.

You may know that it only makes sense to memoize the last 2 or 3 values, because you will never use values older than that.  (Fibonacci's Sequence comes to mind.)

You may be generating a LOT of values on some runs, and just a few on others.

You may want to "throw away" some of the memoized values and start over.  (I memoized a random number generator this way, so I could replay the sequence of random numbers that built a certain structure, while some other parameters of the structure had been changed.)

Memoization as an optimization depends on the search for the memoized value being a lot cheaper than recomputation of the value.  This in turn depends on the ordering of the input requests.  This has implications for the memoization database: Does it use a stack, an array of all possible input values (which may be very large), a bucket hash, or a b-tree?

The memoizing compiler has to either provide a "one size fits all" memoization, or it has to provide lots of possible alternatives, and parameters to control the alternatives.  At some point, it becomes easier for everyone to require the user to provide his own memoization.

Comment: Still think that makes sense to have default one that stores all values or specified. Having kind of annotation above target function like. @Memo(1..10) def foo(i:Int)

Answer (score 23):

Because compilers have to emit semantically correct programs. You can't memoize a function without changing program semantics unless it is [referentially transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)). In most programming languages not all functions are referentially transparent (pure functional programming languages are an exception) so you can't memoize everything. But then a mechanism is needed for detecting referential transparency and that is too hard.

Comment: sometimes people downvote for no reason at all, I guess it's just for fun, or they are bots.

Comment: You have to have some rep to be able to downvote - unlikely to be a bot.

Answer (score 13):

In Haskell, [memoization is automatic](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization#Memoization_with_recursion) for (pure) functions you've defined that take no arguments.  And the Fibonacci example in that Wiki is really about the simplest demonstrable example I would be able to think of either.

Haskell can do this because your pure functions are defined to produce the same results *every* time; of course, monadic functions that depend on side effects won't be memoized.

I'm not sure what the upper limits are -- obviously, it won't memoize more than the available memory.  And I'm also not sure offhand if the memoization occurs at compile-time (if the values *can* be determined at compile-time), or if it *always* occurs the first time the function is called.

Answer (score 12):

Clojure has a memoize function (http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/memoize):

```
memoize
function

Usage: (memoize f)

Returns a memoized version of a referentially transparent function. The
memoized version of the function keeps a cache of the mapping from arguments
to results and, when calls with the same arguments are repeated often, has
higher performance at the expense of higher memory use.
```

Comment: I'm not sure this counts. He specifically said "language feature" not "implemented in a library". Although in any Lisp, the difference between language features and library implementations is slight, so +1 anyway.

Comment: @A. Levy: Also, it's from `clojure.core`, which basically means it's a builtin language feature, although not as fundamental as one of the 10 or so "special forms".  As you say, the rules are different in Lisp :)

Answer (score 7):

Because you shouldn't implement something as a language feature when it can easily be implemented in the language itself. A memoization feature belongs in a library, which is exactly where most languages put it.

Comment: you can implement object oriented programming in C through virtual tables etc, but that did not prevent the creation of C++...

Comment: The word 'easily' in my answer is not there by accident.

If you intend to copy the actual features of C++, and not just create shallow mimics, then you can not simply extend C with these C++ capabilities 'through virtual tables'. You would effectively be rewriting half of a C++ compiler. 

In contrast, a general memoization function is a few lines in any decent language. Adding a keyword for that is a bad idea. I'll leave it to the Lisp community to explain why.

Comment: One of the key concepts of C++ (even more than OO, I'd say, since it's a special brand of "OO" that doesn't meet Kay's definition) is "only pay for what you use", which is difficult-to-impossible to do on top of C, at least with any reasonable syntax (since its macro language is so weak).  In contrast, memoization is easy to do in almost any language, and adds minimal syntactic overhead.

Comment: Do "most languages" really have this in libraries? Offhand I can't think of a language that has a standard library facility for memoization.

Comment: "a general memoization function is a few lines in any decent language": I guess I don't know any decent language... well, maybe Haskell, but why should I write a memoization library while it's allready built-in ?

Answer (score 6):

**A)** Memoization trades space for time. I imagine that this can turn out to a fairly unbound property, in the sense, that the amount of data programs or libraries would have to store could consume large parts of memory really quick.

For a couple of languages, memoization is easy to implement and easy to customize for the given requirements.

As an example take some natural language processing on large bodies of text, where you don't want to compute basic properties of texts (word count, frequency, cooccurrences, ...) over and over again. In that case a memoization in combination with object serialization can be useful as opposed to memory caching, since you may run your application multiple times on unchanged corpora.

**B)** Another aspect: It's not true, that all functions or methods yield the same output for a same given input. Anyway some keyword or syntax for memoization would be necessary, along with configuration (memory limits, invalidation policy, ...) ...

Answer (score 2):

Your question also leaves open the solution of your learning more languages.  I think that Lisp supports memoization, and I know that Mathematica does.

Comment: I know six or seven, but I don't like pure functional ones (hence no lisp) nor something you have to pay big bucks to get access to (and in any case I would not need it) ;)

Comment: i apologize bc this thread is old, but i have to.  lisp is not pure functional.  it is functional, but impure

Answer (score 2):

In order for memoization to work as a language feature there would be a couple requirements.

1. The compiler would need to be identify valid functions for memoization (e.g. they are referentially transparent).
2. The run-time would have to be able to intelligently select candidates for memoization without slowing down the overall performance.

There are some assumptions in the other language, but if we can have performance gains by just-in-time compilation of hot-spots in a Java VM, then one can surely write an automated memoziation system.

While non-trivial I think this is all theoretically possible to get performance gains in a language (especially an interpreted one) and is a worthwhile area for research.

Answer (score 1):

Not all the languages natively support function decorators. I guess it would be a more general approach to support rather than supporting just memoization.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the question. Why it should? As someone has said, it can be put in a library so no need of add syntax to the language, it's only usable on pure functions which are hard to identify automatically(unless you force the programmer to annotate them). It's also very hard to determine if memoization is going to speed up things or not. I don't think it's a desirable feature for a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I really think such an option should be.

In data processing tasks there is an immutable input data (as time series, for example, where for a given time as soon as a value is known, it can never change). Taking in mind today RAM affordability, if a function result only depends on such immutable data, it is rational to memoize it rather than reread every time it's needed. Currently I have (in Scala and C#) to manually introduce an in-memory storage table and write 3 functions instead of one - one reading a value from file/db/ws, one storing it into an in-memory table, one to wrap them and read from memory if available or call the raw function if not. I think this could and should be implemented as a keyword and done behind the scenes.