# Functional languages & support for memoization

Tags: functional-programming, memoization

Do any of the current crop of popular functional languages have good support for memoization & if I was to pick one on the strength of its memoisation which would you recommend & why?

Update: I'm looking to optimise a directed graph (where nodes could be functions or data). When a node in the graph is updated I would like the values of other nodes to be recalculated only if they depend the node that changed.

Update2: require free or open-source language/runtime.

Comment: Interesting and relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932968/why-memoization-is-not-a-language-feature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Haskell, Conal Elliott has posted a beautiful blog entry on [functional memo tries](http://conal.net/blog/posts/elegant-memoization-with-functional-memo-tries/).  The work is extraordinarily clever and quite deep, and Conal later extended it to [polymorphic functions](http://conal.net/blog/posts/memoizing-polymorphic-functions-part-one/).  No matter what language you use, this stuff is highly recommended, because it **uncovers the deep ideas** underlying memoization in functional languages.

However, looking at your update, it's not clear that memoization is really what you want.  Your expanded problem statement (propagating updates through a directed graph) is an almost textbook example of **incremental computation**, on which a great deal of work has been done by Bob Harper and [Umut Acar](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~umut/).  I believe they have a free library written in Standard ML.  Look at Umut's page on [*self-adjusting computation*](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~umut/projects/self-adjusting-computation/index.html).

Comment: @Norman - Thanks for the interesting links & agreed, while making the updates, and after having thought about it some more, I realised memoization was probably not the solution.... but I'm still keen to know how deep memoization support can go.

Comment: Following the link on self-adjusting computation you included above yielded http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~umut/papers/toplas06.html which looks to be exactly what I want - An "Adaptive Functional Language" .... "a call-by-value functional language extended with adaptivity primitives." .... "As an adaptive program executes, the underlying system represents the data and control dependences in the execution in the form of a dynamic dependence graph . When the input to the program changes, a change propagation algorithm updates the output and the dynamic dependence graph by propagating changes"

Comment: For a more elegant approach to polymorphic memoization (using deep & elegant properties rather than operational magic), see the post *[Memoizing polymorphic functions via unmemoization](http://conal.net/blog/posts/memoizing-polymorphic-functions-via-unmemoization)*, which consists mainly of my ruminations on Dan Piponi's post *[Memoizing Polymorphic Functions with High School Algebra and Quantifiers](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/11/memoizing-polymorphic-functions-with.html)*.

Answer (score 4):

On Haskell, see [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization) for a start.

For Lisp,  [this](http://tfeb.org/lisp/hax.html#MEMOIZE) was the first hit from Google that looked relevant.

For F# [this](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/8896.aspx) might be a good place to start.

Now I'm done Googling for you. Is any of this *good* support ?  You decide :-)

Oh, I'd recommend Mathematica, but I understand that a lot of people are put off by its price tag.  Strictly speaking it's probably more of a term-rewriting system than a functional programming system, and it's not pure in any senses of the word.  But it does do memoization.

EDIT: I forgot Erlang, which has a lot of traction at the moment -- I don't know how but I expect it can do memoization.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you don't want memoization at all, you want precise dependency tracking.
You could use the Haskell Functional Graph Library (fgl) to create ur directed graph, then use the successor function to know precisely which nodes to update:
  http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/fgl

This paper will greatly aid ind understanding the docs:
  http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/

The successor function is named suc, in module Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph

Going in a different direction, one popular functional language that supports this is Excel. :)